# Displaying a string in two lines in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

How can I display string in two lines like
AlphaBravo is a string i am receiving in crystal report
i want to display it as:-
Alpha
Bravo
The code is as follows in my content field

```
Replace (Alpha@Bravo,'@',' + Chr(13) + ')
```

The above didnt work for me

Comment: Based on which you will divide the string?

Comment: @kalyan I want to replace "@" with a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you have given in your edit is correct but little modification, see below code

```
Replace (Alpha@Bravo,'@', Chr(10))

        or

 Replace (Alpha@Bravo,'@', Chr(13))
```